# Moving one item in Org Table from col 1 to col 2 problem

Tags: org-mode

Given the following structure:

```
| A |  |  |  |
| B |  |  |  |
```

I want the following:

```
|A |  |   |  |
|  |  | B |  |
```

Question:
Is there a way to move single elements between columns?
What I know right now I can only move whole columns.

Comment: There is a quite easy way to restrict editing commands to a range of rows (especially also a single row). Just break the table by inserting a newline before the first line of the row range and after the last line of the row range apply your editing and remove the newlines afterwards. If it takes takes too many keystrokes for you and you need it very often you can put this into a command and bind it to some key sequence.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using narrowing, just narrow the table to the single row with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and apply `M-<Right>` and then widen with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> .

For another solution check [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html) explaining why this is not in Org mode and how to add custom functions to add it self.

Comment: Cool! I've used `org-narrow-to-block`, `org-narrow-to-subtree` and `widen` but I didn't know that `org-narrow-to-element` would only show a single row of a table. Very nice solution!